# Is there a minimum size for Chanuka flames?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, shiurim-measurements, menora-chanukia

Do the flames atop the chanukiya need to be a certain size to be valid? At the extreme, are tiny (but sustained) balls of blue flame sufficient?

Comment: I would be so surprised if the answerer actually gives a source. This is a good question, but I don't see it being mentioned in any Sefarim. I could be wrong, but I doubt it.

Comment: I bet it's just about how much/what type of pirsumei nissa you are going for. At a window, a little ball is pointless, but on your table it could be fine.

Comment: @double aa I would go as far to say that based on what you said this is probably a Miswa Min HaMuvhar but not MeIkar HaDin.

Comment: AFAIK, as long as you can see the flames it's ok...

Comment: @ShmuelL and as long as you are not putting your house at danger of fire breaking out because of the too big fire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fire is a fire is a fire - See [OH 673(1)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%92)

> ואע"פ שאין השמנים נמשכים אחר הפתילה ואין האור נתלה יפה באותם הפתילות
>
> Even though the wicks don't absorb the oil well and the light [fire] doesn't attach well to those wicks (--translation mine)

(i.e. even if your lights are poor, your still yotzeh the mitzvah).

That being said, the מצוה מן המבחר is to use materials that will give off a light that is "pure and clean" (Rama, ibid.). The Mishna Berura also something along the lines of what @doubleaa said: The goal here is Persumei Nisa. Hence, if people can't see them, you may have an issue at hand.

Comment: Mbrevda, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this source and insight! I look forward to seeing you around.